# Compute efficiently a pairwise ranking loss function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently implementing http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P15-1061 in tensorflow.

I have implemented the pairwise ranking loss function (section 2.5 of the paper) as follow :

```
s_theta_y = tf.gather(tf.reshape(s_theta, [-1]), y_true_index)
s_theta_c_temp = tf.reshape(tf.gather(tf.reshape(s_theta, [-1]), y_neg_index), [-1, classes_size])
s_theta_c = tf.reduce_max(s_theta_c_temp, reduction_indices=[1])
```

I had to use tf.gather rather than tf.gather_nd because the latter is not yet implemented with gradient descent. I also had to transform all indices to be correct with the flatten matrix.

If tf.gather_nd was implemented with gradient descent, my code would have been as follow :

```
s_theta_y = tf.gather_nd(s_theta, y_t_index)
s_theta_c_temp = tf.gather_nd(s_theta, y_neg_index)
s_theta_c = tf.reduce_max(s_theta_c_temp, reduction_indices=[1])
```

s_theta is the computed score for each class label, as in the paper.
y_true_index contains the index of the true class, in order to compute s_theta_y. y_neg_index is the index of all the negative classes, its dimensions is either #class-1 or #class is the relation is classified as other.

However, several sentences are classified as Other and so, s_theta_y
doesn't exist and we shouldn't take it into account for the calculation. To handle such case, I have a constant factor of 0 which cancel the term, and to have the same dimension vector for the negative class, I just copy a random value of the index, because at the end, we are only interested in the max value among all negative classes (and not the index).

Is there a more efficient way to compute those terms in the loss function ? I have the impression that using tf.gather with so much reshape is very slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly it sounds like gather_nd is what you want, but until gradients are implemented there, I wouldn't hesitate to use your reshape() solution, since reshape() is practically free.

The [C++ implementation of the reshape() op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/reshape_op.h) looks like it's doing a lot of work, but it's all just quick error checking on the shape information. The "work" happens in CopyFrom on line 90, which sounds like it might be expensive, but is actually just a pointer copy ([CopyFrom](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h#L169) calls [CopyFromInternal](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.cc#L495) which copies the pointer).

This makes complete sense: the underlying buffer is just a flat array of numbers in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), and that ordering does not depend on the shape information. For the same reason, something like tf.transpose() *will* require copying in general.